# Efficient way to custom serialize a joda LocalDate

Tags: java, serialization, jodatime

I need to write a custom serializer for a joda LocalDate. Serializer should be as fast as possible, and create an output which is as small as possible.

I can send basic Java primitives and objects over the wire, e.g. long, boolean, int, String, etc, but not objects of any Joda types.

I've noticied an internal "iLocalMillis" field which is not publicly accessable. Also not sure how to serialize the Chronology component...

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Do you use different chronologies within your app? If not (if it's always the Gregorian calendar), that would simplify things...

Comment: I really hope for you that you just need `ISOChronology` (the default). Otherwise you get very complex state - see for example [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/serialized-form.html#org.joda.time.chrono.GJChronology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is sufficient and simple if `ISOChronology` is enough for you:

1. Write the attributes `getYear()`, `getMonthOfYear()` and `getDayOfMonth()` out.
2. Read the three mentioned integer attributes and use [this constructor of LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#LocalDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

In the case you need to serialize the `Chronology` then you are a little bit out of luck and have to study the serialization form of each concrete chronology you need as published in JavaDoc. One example is the serialization form of [GJChronology](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/serialized-form.html#org.joda.time.chrono.GJChronology).